# How to get set up FQDN for Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am using Azure Container Registry to store my private docker image and **Azure Container Instance** to deploy it.

I get a public IP address which is OK for verification and simple preview, but not usable (or shareable with customer) since the IP address is dynamic.

Is there a way to set up fully qualified domain name that i can use instead of changing IP address on every container restart?

Browsing through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/) does not reveal anything about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up fully qualified domain name that i can use
>   instead of changing IP address on every container restart?

Unfortunately, for now, Azure does **not** support to set a static public IP address for instance, Azure Container Instance still in preview.

> In the future, we will expand our networking capabilities to include
>   integration with virtual networks, load balancers, and other core
>   parts of the Azure networking infrastructure.

More information about Azure Container Instance network, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview#public-ip-connectivity).

As a workaround, we can deploy a VM and run docker on it, set static public IP address for this VM, then restart docker we will not lose this public IP address.

Comment: If you restart your container instance you are not guaranteed the same public IP. To work around this, as Jason states we will be supporting FQDNs this month via the API.

Answer (score 8):

You can now set a dns-name-label as a property for your container group. Details are shared in this answer - hope this helps and thanks for being a user!

[Azure Container Group IP Address disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547693/azure-container-group-ip-address-disappeared)

Answer (score 4):

When using a `docker-compose.yml` file on ACI(Azure Container Instances), `domainname` property is used for FQDN.

```yaml
services:
    service-name:
        image: ****
        domainname: **FQDN**
```

Comment: Awesome, although the ip wont remain the same on each restart, the FQDN name will, so you dont really have to change anything on restart

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do it via Azure CLI using the `dns-name-label` flag:

```
az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name mycontainer --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld --dns-name-label aci-demo --ports 80
```

src [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart#create-a-container)

This will result in the following FQDN: `aci-demo.westeurope.azurecontainer.io` (westeurope being your location)